# MySQL - Verbose Tag (-v) Output Only Server Responses

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

I have a large .sql file that I am reading into a MySQL server using the following code...

```
mysql -vvv -u root < "%DIRECTORY%load_script.sql"
```

When I load this in I get the a whole heap of responses in command prompt in the following format...

[image: Sample Verbose Query Response]

However, I only want to see the response from the server that is encapsulated in red in the image above (success/failure status of query and record summary).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/API_574_STRUCTURAL_THICKNESS.CSV"
INTO TABLE API_574_STRUCTURAL_THICKNESS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/DAMAGE_MECHANISM_LIST.CSV"
INTO TABLE DAMAGE_MECHANISM_LIST
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/STATUSES.CSV"
INTO TABLE STATUSES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/INSPECTION_STATUSES.CSV"
INTO TABLE INSPECTION_STATUSES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/REMEDIATION_STATUSES.CSV"
INTO TABLE REMEDIATION_STATUSES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/CML_TYPES.CSV"
INTO TABLE CML_TYPES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/EQUIPMENT.CSV"
INTO TABLE EQUIPMENT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/DAMAGE_MECHANISM.CSV"
INTO TABLE DAMAGE_MECHANISM
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/CML.CSV"
INTO TABLE CML
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/USERS/RHINO113/GOOGLE DRIVE/REPOS/REPO - IDMAS VESSELS APPLICATION/1.0 BACK END/1.2 SERVER CONFIG SCRIPT/2.2 IDMAS VESSELS DATA/INSPECTION.CSV"
INTO TABLE INSPECTION
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: I think verbose is to show everything (using or expressed in more words than are needed). So think you need to remove verbose to show less info then you are currently getting

Comment: @davejal If i remove the -vvv tag, then the system does not output any information, if I have one -v tag the system only outputs the sent SQL string and no server response, if I have a -vv tag then I get the same results as above. So none of these options really give me what I want.

Comment: which version of MySQL are you running? I just tried my setup without the `v` switch and I get exactly what you want check it out here http://imgur.com/a/zLyoj

Comment: could you add your sql script maybe there is something there

Comment: @davejal Mysql version 5.7.14. Hmm I looked at your image. Where have you specified the -v switch? I don't see it in the command prompt dialog box or in the content of your queries? I will update the question with the SQL script in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

To filter your verbose MySQL output, pipe your output through `grep`. You should test and adjust this command to be more robust for your use case. Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
mysql -vvv -u root < "%DIRECTORY%load_script.sql" | grep -i -e 'query' -e 'records'
```

This command will take your mysql output, and look for lines containing the word `query` or `records`. `-i` makes `grep` case-insensitive, so you may get extra lines. Failed queries may not output. I did not test that far.

This [blog pos](https://www.shellhacks.com/grep-or-grep-and-grep-not-match-multiple-patterns/)t looks helpful, and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) is the GNU documentation for `grep`.